# How to change Gradio Default Background Color?

Tags: deployment, chatbot, openai-api, gradio-chatinterface

I am creating a chatbot that is deployed on huggingface spaces using gradio. I have set the theme to have blue and teal. On huggingface spaces app it shows the colors i want. I want to use the iframe automatically generated by huggingface to embed this chatbot into a website, however gradio themes are not following through.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMb7e.png)
I created a dummy webpage to test it, but it shows up with the dark interface. I have inspected the code on the website and the class = dark. How can I embed this chatbot into the website while keeping my color scheme?

I have tried to add themes everywhere, and followed this tutorial to "force" my color scheme [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI4Nn.png)

However the issue persists. I tried to manually change the inspect code to class = light and it works fine but of course once i reset the page the light theme changes to dark